# tomcat and jre settiings

Tags: tomcat, java

I am configuring 2 tomcat to use JRE 
as shown below

```
Server1

 - tomcat1
 - jre1

Server2

 - tomcat2
 - jre2
```

tomcat1 will  use jre 1 and tomcat2 will use jre2

This is working fine.

> But  if i make tomcat1 and tomcat2 to use one jre , a common one.   is
>   this setting will make a difference from previous one  ?

Comment: @shinynewbike Just want to know .

Answer (score 1):

if the 2 JREs have the same version and your tomcats can run on the same JRE then No it shouldn't make any difference.
The issue is like you are trying to run two diffrent java apps or multiple instances of the same app at the same time.

So what is the problem? For sure there is no problem at all.

But make sure that the tomcats doesn't have the same binding address to not get in an address binding exception.